# How to fix borrowed value does not live long enough in `while`

Tags: rust

```rust
enum TreeNode {
    Child(Rc<RefCell<[TreeNode]>>),
    Leaf(i32),
    Nil,
}

struct Tree {
    root: TreeNode,
}

impl Tree {
    fn new() -> Tree {
        Tree {
            root: TreeNode::Nil,
        }
    }

    fn traverse(&mut self) {
        let mut node = &self.root;

        let mut parent = None;
        while let TreeNode::Child(child) = node {
            let mut child_mut = child.borrow_mut();
            child_mut[1] = TreeNode::Leaf(1);
            parent = Some(node);
            node = &child_mut[0]; // error: borrowed value does not live long enough
        }
    }
}
```

The compile error is

```bash
error[E0597]: `child_mut` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:59:21
   |
59 |             node = &child_mut[0];
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
60 |         }
   |         -
   |         |
   |         `child_mut` dropped here while still borrowed
   |         borrow might be used here, when `child_mut` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `std::cell::RefMut<'_, [TreeNode]>`
```

I know the error reason because `child_mut` is a temp variant in `while` scope, so rust won't allow assign its reference to `node` but I don't know how to fix it. Help needed.

Comment: You can't keep references to things inside of the `RefCell`.

Comment: `borrow_mut()` returns a reference that's only valid within that narrow scope where it's created. You might need `Rc` or `Arc` here instead, using `clone()`.

Comment: Can you provide some code snippet to show how to use RC. Thank you @tadman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rc` with `RefCell` is pretty tricky. You have to `Rc::clone` pretty liberally so that values are owned instead of references, as references won't live long enough. General rule of thumb: if you have a `&T` that won't live long enough, you should find a way to change it to a `&Rc<T>` or `&Rc<RefCell<T>>` so that you can `Rc::clone` it to make it owned.

This should work (at least, it compiles and looks correct):

```rust
fn traverse(&mut self) {
    if let TreeNode::Child(root) = &self.root {
        let mut node = Rc::clone(root);
        let mut parent = None;

        while let TreeNode::Child(child) = &Rc::clone(&node).borrow()[1] {
            let child = Rc::clone(child);
            child.borrow_mut()[1] = TreeNode::Leaf(1);
            parent = Some(node);
            node = child;
        }
    }
}
```